# Lombok @Singular has no effect in child class with @Builder on Constructor

Tags: java, annotations, builder, lombok

So I just discovered the Lombok `@Builder` annotation and I love it. Especially with the `@Singular` annotations for Collections.

In the case of inheritance I've read that the most effective way to create the Builder for the child class is as follows:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Customer extends User {

    @Singular
    private List<Order> orders;

    @Builder
    public Customer(String username, String password, String email, List<Order> orders) {
        super(username, password, email);
        this.orders = orders;
    }   
}
```

The only problem with this approach is that the `@Singular` on the orders field has no effect. It is only possible to pass a List of Order to the Builder that is created, not a single order. Is there a better workaround for this situation or must I accept it the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `@Singular` annotation to the `List<Order> orders` parameter in the constructor of the `Customer` class to get the desired effect.

```
@Builder
public Customer(String username, String password, String email, @Singular List<Order> orders) {
    super(username, password, email);
    this.orders = orders;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was just what I was looking for but I did not find it in any docs or examples